# Put an ObjectOutputStream on AWS s3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, objectoutputstream, apache-spark-mllib

I use spark mllib to create a linear regression model. I then tried to save the model in an ObjectOutputStream, so I could put it on s3 and read it later. The following is my code:

```
val algorithm = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
val model = algorithm.run(trainingData)

val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("myKey", "mySecretKey");
val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myModelFile"));
oos.writeObject(model);
oos.close();

s3Client.putObject("myBucket", "myPath", oos)
```

Then I got complains at line:

```
s3Client.putObject("myBucket", "myPath", oos)
```

What did I miss and how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you get a stack trace? Could you provide that?

Comment: No, the code doesn't even compile, showing red on eclipse directly.